# Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake' when installing pyarrow

Tags: cmake, streamlit, pyarrow

I'm trying to install streamlit, which requires pyarrow. But when I install pyarrow, I get the errow "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'". I have already installed cmake (version 3.27.4)

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/helennie/Projects/LLM/venv2/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
          from cmake import cmake
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
      error: command '/Users/helennie/Projects/LLM/venv2/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm running macOS 10.12.6 and using python 3.11 in a virtual environment. I've tried with python 3.7 and 3.8 - no success.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: "I have already installed cmake (version 3.27.4)" - You have installed a **program** named `cmake`. The error message is about **Python package** named `cmake`.

Answer (score 1):

This error basically translates to:

> pip couldn't find a pre-built version of the PyArrow on https://pypi.org for your operating system and Python version so it tried to build PyArrow from scratch which failed.

It's fairly common for Python packages to only provide pre-built versions for recent versions of common operating systems and recent versions of Python itself. In PyArrow's case for macOS, that means macOS 10.14 or newer. I can tell this is the because I went to https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/#files and see files with the string "macosx_10_14" in them and none that reference an older version.

The most straightforward way to fix this is to upgrade macOS to at least 10.14 and try to install streamlit/PyArrow again.

Comment: That makes sense - time for a new laptop I suppose! Thanks for the help.